# React router v4 error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Router is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, react-router, react-router-v4

I am using react-router v4 for a project 
here are my CDNs

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/4.0.0-alpha.3/react-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
```

and here is my code

```
ReactDOM.render(

  <Router>
  <Route path="/" component={LoginForm} />
        </Router>

    ,document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

the loginform code look like this

```
var LoginForm = React.createClass({
render: function() {
return (
    <div> 
    <div id="postdiv">
<form id="customerForm" data-toggle="validator">
<div className="form-group">
<span className="label label-default">Login</span>
...
```

I am getting this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Router is not defined
at eval (eval at n.run (browser.min.js:3), <anonymous>:79:3)
at Function.n.run (browser.min.js:3)
at l (browser.min.js:3)
at i (browser.min.js:3)
```

Comment: You need webpack to compile JSX and then you can import react router like this: import { Router } from 'react-router';

Comment: Try to use the last release of React Router v4 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/4.0.0-beta.5/react-router.min.js

Answer (score 0):

When you `import react-router` from the `cdn` you can use it like

```
    <ReactRouter.Router>
       <ReactRouter.Route path="/" component={LoginForm} />
    </ReactRouter.Router>
```

Also from your comment it seems like that you have either not exported the `LoginForm` component or not imported with properly

You need to do the following

```
var LoginForm = React.createClass({
render: function() {
return (
    <div> 
    <div id="postdiv">
<form id="customerForm" data-toggle="validator">
<div className="form-group">
<span className="label label-default">Login</span>
...
)}
})

export default LoginForm;
```

Also you need to import it like

```
<script src="path/to/loginFormFile"></script>
```

Comment: already tried this but gives me:  "Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in."

Comment: are  you exporting and importing  the login form component

Comment: i think as iam not using npm , i dont need to use import/export , just CDNs , am i right ??  *sorry i am new to reactjs :D*

Comment: @OmarShiha . I think you will need to do that like i have mentioned in my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: iam not exporting nor importing any thing as they are all under one script "<script type="text/babel">" i havent separated them yet , and this is another issue iam facing , as iam using spring boot as backend so there is a certain dir to make the backend app see the .js react files

Comment: Hi I Have the very same problem as you, did you got any solution?